Abstract one layer of database connection to another class
I might add more methods but currently I have this design:
So connectionString comes from IOptions pattern.
Then for each method I am repeating myself to open the connection in this part of the code but I do need the connectionString for that:
using IDbConnection myConnection = new SnowflakeDbConnection(connectionString: _connectionString);
myConnection.Open();

Note: SnowflakeDbConnection is not mine. It is from the NuGet package for accessing Snowflake from .NET
I wanted to see if you can suggest a better design? This is how I am doing it now:
public class MyDatabaseDataService: IMyDatabaseDataService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public MyDatabaseDataService(IOptions<ApplicationOptions> options)
    {
        this._connectionString = options.Value.MyDatabaseConnectionString;
    }
    
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(string selectSqlCommand)
    {
        using IDbConnection myConnection = new SnowflakeDbConnection(connectionString: _connectionString);
        myConnection.Open();

        var result = await myConnection.QueryAsync<T>(selectSqlCommand).ConfigureAwait(false);

        myConnection.Close();

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetSingleOrDefaultById<T>(string sqlCommand, int id)
    {
        using IDbConnection myConnection = new SnowflakeDbConnection(connectionString: _connectionString);
        myConnection.Open();

        var result = await myConnection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<T>(sqlCommand, new { id });

        return result;
    }
}

and the DI for MyDatabaseDataService is done in Program.cs like this:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyDatabaseDataService, MyDatabaseDataService>();


More a question for CodeReview than StackOverflow. However, IMHO I think there is nothing wrong here.

You could always provide a method private IDbConnection _conn; public IDbConnection GetConnection() { _conn ??= new SnowflakeDbConnection(connectionString: _connectionString); if (_conn.State != Open) _conn.Open(); return _conn; } (You'll want to clean up the code there, but the idea is sound, I think).

@HereticMonkey I see. So just put the code in a private method and then call the private method in my public interface methods

Yeah, or make a base class that your database services implement that has a protected or public method. Either way.

In order to enhance the design of your MyDatabaseDataService class and avoid redundant connection handling code, you can refactor it by encapsulating the connection logic into separate async methods. By creating private methods for opening and closing the connection, you centralize the connection management and ensure consistency across database operations.
This can be implemented by creating a dedicated SnowflakeDatabaseProvider class. This class handles opening and closing connections, and exposes methods for executing queries

@MdFaridUddinKiron would you mind post a version of your design idea as an answer please ?
